# Is my transaction xml to java config conversion right?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

Here's the portion of our xml that is related to transaction management

```
<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<tx:advice id="txAdvice"/>    

<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">

    <aop:pointcut id="transactionalMethods"
        expression="@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="transactionalMethods" />

</aop:config>
```

I came up with this

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement( proxyTargetClass = true )
public class TransactionConfig
{
    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager( final DataSource dataSource, final EntityManagerFactory emf ) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource( dataSource );
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory( emf );
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

and it seems to work, but reading the config I can't help but wonder if I'm supposed to use `mode = ASPECTJ`, but when I tried that the context blew up with an exception about not able to inject "Concrete class", as some things depend on the class and not the interface.

I'm not sure why we added that pointcut, or whether we make use of it, if I have to rewrite it as a pointcut, I'm actually not sure how I should do that.

*Do I need to add something more to get parity? is this already the same? if I need to add more what should I write?*

*update*

When trying

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy( proxyTargetClass = true )
@EnableTransactionManagement( mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ )
```

and aspectj itself was working via our xml config (the aspects do work in our xml config)

```
<context:spring-configured/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

with deps

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
```

I get errors like

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myapp.CatalogItemViewDao com.myapp.ProviderTestHistoryDao.catalogItemViewDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myapp.CatalogItemViewDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myapp.CatalogItemViewDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
```

Answer (score 1):

No you dont need to set mode = ASPECTJ , unless you expect transaction to be applied on self invocation calls, means calling from another methods in the same class. Other mode proxy which default, will only support calls that coming externally through proxy interfaces.

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
>   self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual
>   transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Transactional. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide
>   the expected behaviour so you should not rely on this feature in your
>   initialization code,

if you set mode = aspectj , it will use spring AspectJ weaving using byte code modification for affected class and methods. But This will require spring-aspect.jar and CGLIB jars to be present in the class path.

And,

if you are just using @Transactional annotation you don't need define any aop point cuts. You only need to define the transaction manager

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative

Comment: yeah, but I'm trying to figure out if there was a reason we defined that point cut... the documentation isn't entirely clear on what breaks with self invocation... I'm going to assume that it means an outer method without `@Transactional` calling an inner method that has `@Transactional`, which us doing somewhere wouldn't entirely surprise me... 

Which is why I'm trying to reach parity... (also noting that cglib is not a dep provided by spring platform... nore is it required to make normal aspectj work, we have that working). updated question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ASPECTJ (with spring-aspects-4.x.y.RELEASE.jar), a pointcut definition shouldn't be necessary.
Take a look at `aop.xml` in the mentioned jar, the AnnotationTransactionAspect is defined there.

Comment: hmm... updated the question to include more about my attempt and what I believe are the relevant deps